# Django Import-export: Import CSV files errors

Tags: django, django-import-export

I`ve spent a few hours trying to debug this issue. I am trying to import a catalog of product into my app. I am using Django Import-export to import a csv file. I have tried to import it via the admin site and via a simple upload file. In both case, I am encountering some errors. Would you have an idea how to resolve them?

**1st Method: Import the csv file via the admin site**

Error encountered: *Imported file has a wrong encoding: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 13365: character maps to*

It looks like this method cannot accept some character(""). How can I change my code to accept any character? I`ve already removed the following characters: £, - and try to encode it in UTF-8. I have also done a search to remove every non ASCII characters(128-255)

**2eme Method: Import the csv file via the website**

Error encountered: *'MultiValueDict' object is not callable*

**views.py**

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_format = request.POST.get('file-format')
        product_resource = ProductResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_products = request.FILES['Price_List']

        if file_format == 'CSV':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_products.read().decode('utf-8'),format='csv')
            result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)                                                                 
        elif file_format == 'JSON':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_products.read().decode('utf-8'),format='json')
            # Testing data import
            result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True) 

        if not result.has_errors():
            # Import now
            product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)

    return render(request, 'catalog/simple_upload.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Product

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = False
```

**simple_upload.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<h3>Import Data</h3>
<p>importing to database</p>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="importData">
    <p>Please select format of file.</p>
    <select name="file-format" class="form-control my-3">
        <option selected>Choose format...</option>
        <option>CSV</option>
        <option>JSON</option>
      </select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Import</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: can you post an example file and stack traces? What encoding is your file in?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, Here is a link to the file that I am trying to upload[link] https://file.io/6ZLlxATV, What I would like to know is which character I need to remove. I could spend some time to clean it eventually.

Comment: link gives a 404

Comment: I have just uploaded it on my dropbox [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6zk1h30rhxe7jf/Price_List.csv?dl=0, let me know if you can download it, otherwise, I`ll find another way

Comment: can you verify what encoding the file is in at the point that `import_data()` is called?

Comment: It`s encoded in UTF-8,I`ve tried different encoding as well using Notepad ++

Comment: If you can reproduce it locally and consistently please post an issue on the [github issues page](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues).  Obviously give us enough information so that we can reproduce it.